# Fraction Value Operations in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I want to make a program where fraction  values can be operated mathematically.
I've made a code but it show me an error.

**TypeError: both arguments should be  Rational instances.**

```
print "We'll ask you for two fraction values."
print "After taking values from you, we'll use python built in operaters to make it happen."

from fractions import *
value_1_one = raw_input("Please enter 1st value : ")

value_1_two = raw_input("Please enter 1st two value : ")

value_2_one = raw_input("Please enter 2nd one value.")

value_2_two = raw_input("Please enter 2nd two value.")

vaule_1 = Fraction(value_1_one, value_1_two)
value_2 = Fraction(value_2_one, value_2_two)
print "We have %i and %i as values." % (value_one, value_two)
print "What kind of operation you would like to make."
print "Like Add, Sub, Multi, Devide"

op_kind = raw_input(">>>")
if "Add" in op_kind:
    print (value_1 + value_2)
elif "Sub" in op_kind:
    print (value_1 - value_2)
elif "Multi" in op_kind:
    print (value_1 * value_2)
elif "Devide" in op_kind:
    print (value_1 / value_2)
else:
    print "Ask Mr. Ramanuj for further details."
```

Comment: `raw_input()` always returns strings. `Fraction()` expects integers (or other rational numbers).

Comment: Thanks Solved!, Can i take input in cmd like this, 21/34 in one single line.